# How to populate RecyclerView with data which has id=xxxx in Firebase using Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have questions&answers in my `Firebase`. Every question and answer has its own id.

```
MyFirebase
 -answers
 -questions
```

I populated `recyclerView` with questions and when user clicks to any question a new activity will be launched which displays question details. Now I need to display all the answers for that question. Every answer in `Firebase` has QuestionId to which answer belogs.

So how to get answers for a question with some id? Is there any similar methods to filter data like in `SQL` with its WHERE QuestionId = XXXX

```
mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("http://myapp.firebaseio.com/answers");

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.answerList);
        mListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Answers>(this, Answers.class,
                R.layout.single_answer_item, mFirebaseRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView (View v, Answers answers, int position) {
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.answer)).setText(answers.getAnswer());
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.authorid)).setText(answers.getAuthorid());
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.questionid)).setText(answers.getQuestionid());
                                }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
```

**Updated Code**

```
   mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/answers");
    Query queryRef = mFirebaseRef.orderByChild("questionid").equalTo(QidText.toString());
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.answerList);
mListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Answers>(this, Answers.class,
        R.layout.single_answer_item, queryRef) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView (View v, Answers answers, int position) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer)).setText(answers.getAnswer());
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.authorid)).setText(answers.getAuthorid());
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionid)).setText(answers.getQuestionid());


    }
};
listView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
```

Snippet of data

```
myapp:


 -questions
     --KDi2YLc2nzdvJXvntYC
         ---body: "How to create simple q&a android App using Firebase?"
         ---qid:  "-KDi2YLc2nzdvJXvntYC"
         ---title:"How to create simple q&a App?"
         ---topic:"android"
         ---userid:"Admin"

-answers
   --KDi2c8M8sLcSnGLTc8A
    ---answer: "That's very easy, just read Firebase docs"
    ---authorid: "Frank"
    ---questionid:"-KDi2YLc2nzdvJXvntYC"

  --KDi2tiKDnDszAFTRUsE
    ---answer: "hello world"
    ---authorid: "Anna"
    ---questionid:"-KDi2YLc2nzdvJXvntYC"
```

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries

Comment: oh thanks, seems I haven't looked through these page attentively

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How to connect Above code to this??<br/>   ``mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("http://myapp.firebaseio.com/answers");   
        final Query queryRef = mFirebaseRef.orderByChild("questionid").equalTo(QuestionidText.toString());``

Comment: What is the problem? We've answered how to get the answers for a specific question. I am certain that approach works. So you will have to explain what is not working about it. Doesn't `populateView()` get called? Are the wrong answer showing? Does the program crash?

Answer (score 2):

You can read Firebase's document at: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

```
answerRef.orderByChild("question_id").equalTo(id);
```

Comment: -answers --answersUID---questionid

Answer (score 1):

You can pass either a `Firebase` reference or a Firebase `Query` into the `FirebaseListAdapter`'s constructor.

```
mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("http://myapp.firebaseio.com/answers");
Query queryRef = mFirebaseRef.orderByChild("questionid").equalTo(QuestionidText.toString();
mListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Answers>(
                    this, Answers.class,
                    R.layout.single_answer_item, queryRef) {
```

**Update** (March 26, 3:46 pm):

I just added this class [`Activity36160819`](https://github.com/puf/firebase-stackoverflow-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebasedemo/stackoverflow/Activity36160819.java) to [my Github sample repo](https://github.com/puf/firebase-stackoverflow-android) that shows the minimum code needed:

```
public class Activity36160819 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView answersList = new ListView(this);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/36160819/answers");

        Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("questionid").equalTo("-KDi2YLc2nzdvJXvntYC");
        FirebaseListAdapter<DataSnapshot> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<DataSnapshot>(this, DataSnapshot.class,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, queryRef) {
            @Override
            protected DataSnapshot parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                return snapshot;
            }

            @Override
            protected void populateView (View v, DataSnapshot answer, int position) {
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(answer.child("authorid").getValue().toString());
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(answer.child("answer").getValue().toString());
            }
        };
        answersList.setAdapter(adapter);

        setContentView(answersList);
    }
}
```

The corresponding JSON:

```
{
  "questions": {
    "-KDi2YLc2nzdvJXvntYC": {
        "body": "How to create simple q&a android App using Firebase?",
        "qid": "-KDi2YLc2nzdvJXvntYC",
        title: "How to create simple q&a App?",
        topic: "android",
        userid: "Admin"
    }
},
answers: {
    "-KDi2c8M8sLcSnGLTc8A": {
        answer: "That's very easy, just read Firebase docs",
        authorid: "Frank",
        questionid: "-KDi2YLc2nzdvJXvntYC"
    },
    "-KDi2tiKDnDszAFTRUsE": {
        answer: "hello world",
        authorid: "Anna",
        questionid: "-KDi2YLc2nzdvJXvntYC"
    }
  }
}
```

The problems in your code:

- you're looking up the views in `populateView()` on the activity's layout, but they are part of the item's layout: `v.findViewById()`
- hmmm... I thought there was one more thing, but I already forgot about it. If it comes back to me, I'll add it; otherwise this will remain a list-of-one.

Aside from that, please take careful notes of how minimal and complete my answer is. Things that I did different than in your question:

- I included the actual JSON, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.
- I don't use an `Answers` class. While it is fine (and in general a good thing) to use such a class, it is irrelevant to the question. But if you think it *is* relevant, include the minimal code in your question so that we don't have to make it up.
- I construct the `ListView` in the code. I've never done this before, but it means I don't need to include a layout XML in the answer.

For a next question, please do those things in your question. The easier you make the work for the people who know the answer, the more likely it is that they will answer (quickly). Read this [meta about a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: it didn't work. listview isn't populated with sorted data. I added **updated code**

Comment: I suppose every child of **/answers** has unique id. What to do in this case?

Comment: When i changed **queryRef** in FirebaseListAdapter to **mFirebaseRef **, it's populating all the answers, but with **queryRef** no result

Comment: That means your query doesn't match any data. Without seeing a real snippet of your data (as text, no screenshots please), it's impossible to say more.

Comment: added snippet of a question and two answers for it

Comment: no errors, no warning. It isn't populating data to listview